# using local file's classes

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, how can I use classes from local C#  files?

---

In my `chatterbot.cs` file I tried using `ChatterBotAPI.ChatterBot` but I got the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: The type or namespace name `ChatterBotAPI' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I have a directory structure like this:

```
.
├── RunProject.exe
├── bot-api
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── dotnet
│   │   ├── ChatterBotAPI
│   │   │   ├── AssemblyInfo.cs
│   │   │   ├── ChatterBot.cs
│   │   │   ├── ChatterBotAPI.csproj
│   │   │   ├── ChatterBotFactory.cs
│   │   │   ├── ChatterBotSession.cs
│   │   │   ├── ChatterBotThought.cs
│   │   │   ├── ChatterBotType.cs
│   │   │   ├── Cleverbot.cs
│   │   │   ├── Pandorabots.cs
│   │   │   └── Utils.cs
│   │   ├── ChatterBotAPI.sln
│   │   ├── ChatterBotAPITest
│   │   │   ├── AssemblyInfo.cs
│   │   │   ├── ChatterBotAPITest.csproj
│   │   │   └── Main.cs
│   │   └── ChatterBotAPITestVB
│   │       ├── Application.vb
│   │       ├── AssemblyInfo.vb
│   │       └── ChatterBotAPITestVB.vbproj
└── chatterbot.cs
```

How do I use classes from the ChatterBotAPI in my chatterbot.cs file?

---

Note: I am not compiling with the VS IDE.  I am using RunProject.exe, which is a C# .NET binary which runs C# scripts on the fly. It loads and runs chatterbot.cs

Comment: have you added a correct namespace with the `using` keyword?

Comment: *When* do you get this error? The exception means it's runtime, but the error should have been caught at compile time. That's strange.

Comment: @nvoigt I am not compiling, `RunProject.exe` is a C# .NET binary which runs C# scripts on the fly. It loads and runs `chatterbot.cs`.

Comment: Then post it's code, we cannot guess what an unknown executable may or may not be doing.

Comment: Changing "Important note" to "note" really doesn't tell us anything about what RunProject.exe does, and that's the *important* point. A question which is "I'm running an executable that I'm not going to give you details of, and it's not doing what I want it to" is pretty hard for anyone to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike in Java, directory structure isn't very important and isn't coupled to "package" (namespace etc.) structure.

Most of your source files will look like this, with their contents wrapped in a `namespace` block:

**ChatterBot.cs**

```cs
namespace ChatterBotAPI
{
    class ChatterBotFactory()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

As long as your code adds that namespace with `using`, then it can access members of that namespace without even having to fully-qualify them:

**chatterbot.cs**

```cs
using ChatterBotAPI;

...

var botFactory = new ChatterBotFactory();
var bot = botFactory.Create(ChatterBotType.CLEVERBOT);
```

---

If the code you are trying to use is in another project, you will have to reference it.

The best way to develop C# and what I'd recommend you do from now on is inside of projects using the dotnet-cli instead of standalone files using `csc`, then you will be able to reference resources and build with options more easily.

Do

```
$ mkdir MyProject
$ cd MyProject
$ dotnet new console
```

(there are other types of project templates available, `console` is for CLIs/Console Applications)

Then in `MyProject.csproj`, underneath the entire `<PropertyGroup>...</PropertyGroup>` section, add a relative reference to the other project's csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\dotnet\ChatterBotAPI\ChatterBotAPI.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

now edit `Program.cs` to your heart's content (probably fill it with your current `chatterbox.cs`'s contents) and run `dotnet build` and it should all work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the project that is going to use the classes and [add a reference to the file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) containing the classes.

Comment: No thank you, I am not in VS. Please, why do people fail so hard at giving non-IDE-specific answers?

Comment: @minseong: Maybe because you didn't specify it ;) Seems like an important detail.

Comment: How do I add a reference without Visual Studio?

Comment: You will need to consult the documentation for RunProject.exe.

Comment: @JohnWu there must be another way. Why can't I just `#include` a file like in almost every other language?

Comment: @minseong: why do people fail so hard to comprehend the features and limitations of the language they have chosen... and then argue when someone points them out.

Comment: @SamAxe maybe some people have only been using the language for a couple weeks and are used to more lenient interpreted languages and compiled languages with pre-processors.

Comment: @SamAxe and it isn't a limitation, there _must_ be another way. E.g. copy + pasting all code from `ChatterBotAPI` into `chatterbot.cs` might be a possibility, but idk how to actually do that.

Comment: You are right, there is another way.  Open the csproj files in Visual Studio, set a reference, and compile them using the IDE.  If you are asking how to do it with RunProject.exe, you will need to ask someone with knowledge of RunProject.exe.  This is not a general c# question.